# Getting errors when checking framentation status

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, wmi

I am trying to execute the following script on Win7 (x64) to check if any volumes need to be defragmented.

```vbs
Set VolumeList = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Volume")

For Each objVolume in VolumeList
    errResult = objVolume.DefragAnalysis(blnRecommended, objReport)
    If errResult = 0 then

        Wscript.Echo "Used space: " & objReport.UsedSpace
        Wscript.Echo "Volume name: " & objReport.VolumeName
        Wscript.Echo "Volume size: " & objReport.VolumeSize       
        If blnRecommended = True Then
            Wscript.Echo "This volume should be defragged."
        Else
            Wscript.Echo "This volume does not need to be defragged."
        End If
        Wscript.Echo
    Else
        MsgBox errResult
    End If
Next
```

I have tried to run this script on two different Win7 systems.

On the first, I get an `OUT OF MEMORY` error on `GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Volume")`.

On the second, I get no `OUT OF MEMORY` error on `GetObject`, but I get `error 11 (Unknown Error) in errResult (output of DefragAnalysis-method)`.

Both Win7 systems have been installed and configured in the same way.

Perhaps this is not important, but when I check the WMI properties, it says `"Connected to <Local Computer>"` and not (as in Win XP) `"SUCCESSFULLY connected to <Local Computer>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Code works just fine for me, but perhaps it'll help when you explicitly connect to the right namespace:

```
 Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
 Set VolumeList = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume")
```

Also I'd recommend restricting the query to just local disks that have a drive letter assigned to them:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveType = 3 AND DriveLetter IS NOT NULL
```

Use [`WBEMTest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785775) or [`WMIDiag`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/03/wmidiag-2-1-is-here.aspx) to check if your WMI connection is working at all. Check the *Application* and *System* eventlogs for errors and warnings, too.

Comment: Thank you for fast response. I have to wait until tomorrow to check this out, but I will get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error 11 was that the script was not run with elevated privileges. Once it was run as administrator, it worked fine. Thanks